# how to paste a link in google chrome or other web browser using vb.net ?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome

Ive been successful in opening programs like firefox or google chrome from vb.net application using following code

`Dim X As Long`

```
X = Shell("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", 1)
```

can tell me how to paste a specific link in the browser from a click of button of my vb.net application ??

Comment: That's a whole other story, the process won't be the same for every browser, you'll need window-finding external APIs... Also, this is not VB.NET, not VB6. Use `Process.Start`, not `Shell` (and the correct type is usually `Integer`, not `Long`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx